# How to use authStateChange$ amplifyService guard.ts

Tags: angular, observable, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to subscribe to the state changes for AWS Cognito authentication using amplify service in guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AmplifyService }  from 'aws-amplify-angular';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor( private amplifyService: AmplifyService ) {
  }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      return this.amplifyService.authStateChange$.subscribe(authSate => {
      })
  }
}
```

Subsribe to auth states refered from [Subscribe to Authentication State Changes](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/angular?fbclid=IwAR3QYUEwc5Ar_BENPVPkdzCxaJj2Xbz1cfW7sHYs6FwBjBzVGuusb56IE4Y#subscribe-to-authentication-state-changes)

VS code editor throws an error.

```
Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `subscribe`. A [route guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) expects a `boolean`, `Observable<boolean | urlTree>`, `Promise<boolean | urlTree>`

Depending on your rxjs version you may have to use `pipe` method to use map. If 
your rxjs is `5.5+` then use it like:

```
return this.amplifyService.authStateChange$.pipe(
    map(authSate => {
    // do your logic here
    })
)
```

If you have a lesser `rxjs` version then use it like:

```
return this.amplifyService.authStateChange$.map(authSate => {
    // do your logic here
})
```

See a working sample here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dyxaw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I do implement as advised, but it only works if I directly access the url on the address bar not from router link. I guess canactivate does not wait for the API reponse `canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      return this.amplifyService.authStateChange$.pipe(
        map(authState => {
          if(authState.state === 'signedIn') {
            return true;
          }
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
          return false;
        })
      )
  }`

Comment: @sarath: See the example added in the answer. It works for me, can you produce your own stackblitz to show your problem?

Comment: Please find my code in [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-au7td5]. The problem is when i route using routerLink it is not working. If i hit the url directly in the address bar it work. I tried to set a breakpoint, the control is not going into the map method.

Comment: @sarat: your added links says it could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to subscribe to the state change in your guard, but instead just want to know if the user exists (and has been authenticated), then this works:

```
return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user => {
      if (user) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
```